# Product distribution function of two independent random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Why, if $X $ and $Y $ are two independent'', continuous random variables, described by probability density functions $f_X $ and $f_Y $, then the distribution of $Z = XY$ is

$$f_Z(z) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f_X \left( x \right) f_Y \left( z/x \right) \frac{1}{|x|}\, dx $$

as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables)

What I tried until now:

$$ P[XY \le z ] = P[XY \in B] \text{ with } B := \{(x,y)|x\in R, y \le z/x\}$$
The part with $y \le z/x$ is obviously wrong, but with that attempt I got this near to the solution till now:
$$\int_R \int_{(-\infty, z/x)}f_X(x)f_Y(y) dy dx = \int_R \int_{(-\infty, z)}f_X(x)f_Y(y/x) \frac{1}{x} dy dx = {\int_{(-\infty, z)} \int_Rf_X(x)f_Y(y/x) \frac{1}{x} }dx dy $$

Under the wrong assumption I made, the PDF now would be

$$ f_{XY}(y) = \int_Rf_X(x)f_Y(y/x) \frac{1}{x} dx $$

which already is pretty close to where I want to get to

when using the right $B := \{ (x,y)∈R^2|x>0,y≤z/x\}∪\{(x,y)∈R^2|x<0,y≥z/x \} $ as 'Did' suggested, I come to this solution:

$$ P[XY\in B] = \int_{-\infty}^0 \int_z^{\infty} f_X(x)f_Y(y/x)\frac{1}{x} dy dx + \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^z f_X(x)f_Y(y/x)\frac{1}{x} dydx $$

Comment: This is not a "joint" distribution. How would you compute the PDF of XY if you had to?

Comment: @Did then you should correct it on wikipedia, I copied the text from there

Comment: On which WP page?

Comment: @Did the one I linked at "as stated here". I am at the moment editing my question to add details of what I have done until now (how I tried to compute the PDF as you asked)

Comment: Follow the link on the WP page and you should see that "joint" is irrelevant at this place (hence the WP mention is indeed inaccurate).

Comment: @Did I now added everything I have tried until now and deleted the "joint" to avoid confusion

Comment: Right, why not using the correct set $B$ and see what happens? Note that $P[XY \le z ] = P[XY \in B]$ where, forgetting annoying details such as the case $x=0$, $B := \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|xy \le z\}$ is $$B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x\gt0,y \le z/x\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x\lt0,y \ge z/x\}.$$

Comment: @Did, yes I tried that already, but that ends in something very ugly which doesn't look like the right solution at all. I will add it to the question, maybe I did something wrong

Comment: @Did I did as you suggested. I thought I can forget stuff like x=0 because the propability of x being 0 ist 0?

Comment: Perfect--now take your very last formula and *differentiate the RHS with respect to* $z$, this will get you exactly the desired formula for $f_Z(z)$.

Comment: @Did Thanks it worked :)

Comment: Great! Maybe you want to submit your solution as an answer, and even, after a time, to accept it?